Apache Camel spilt, tokenize & streaming - last element
I have the following Camel route
from("file://target/input/?delete=true")
    .log("Started processing [${header.CamelFileNameOnly}] ...")
    .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
    .log("ELEMENT ${body}")
    .process(this::doStuffWithElement);

I'd like to know  somehow when the last line in the file is reached, and then do further processing. I have tried to call end() however in this case it doesn't work as I want.
I'd like to find a solution that could be applied to all sort of sources, eg. an incoming HTTP request, a file downloaded from S3 or SFTP - to name a few.
The idea is to implement a streaming-style processing solution, that doesn't spike in memory consumption, but that it's aware of when the end of the stream is reached correctly.

After .split() is called the exchange will have a property called CamelSplitComplete.
More importantly though, if you want to make .end() work as intended by common sense, you need to call it twice in a row: .end().end() will effectively mean the stream is finished, and after that call you can do further processing. Found this solution because of this (camel-4.6.x).

The Split pattern store exchange properties the state of the splitted element, so you can have a boolean whether its the last. See the docs: https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/eips/split-eip.html#_exchange_properties
